# Ubuntu 14.04 installer for dual-booting with win10 doesn't recognize any partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows, ssd

Im facing the following issue on a new desktop machine:

- I installed Win 10 Insider Preview
- made a fat32 Partition on a USB stick, extracted x64 ubuntu iso to it and set boot flag
- one ssd where win10 and ubuntu should be installed on (of course separate partitions)

Starting this USB stick in uefi works fine, but on Installation there is no option to install Ubuntu next to Windows. Even when I choose "something else" on Installation the whole ssd is displayed as "unallocated" although there is a windows partition which takes roughly half of the size of the ssd. The rest of the ssd is of course unallocated - so I started Disk Management on Win10 and made a NTFS Partition to make it visible for the installer.

But still Ubuntu does not even recognise one of the partitions. [This is what it looks like on Ubuntu Live Session with Gparted](http://i57.tinypic.com/29xfy95.png) (250GB SSD):
and [this is how it looks on Win10 disk Management](http://i59.tinypic.com/2qi2vqc.png) (sorry can't post images directly here because of missing reputation)

C is my Windows system Partition and D is the new NTFs Partition I created of unallocated space with disk Management tool.

How can I access a Partition to install Ubuntu on without formatting the whole SSD? Any help is appreciated thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

I used Ubuntu 15.10 on DVD. In the install there is an option to "erase ubuntu and reinstall". I used that. Also in Win10, you must go into the bios(I use ESC) and select "BIOS setup"(F10). Then select "System Configuration" and go down to "boot options". Enable "Legacy Support". There are two boot orders, move the device reader you are using to the top of both lists. Exit and Save.
Now install Ubuntu. Even then to boot to Ubuntu I must press ESC after the power button, then press F9 and select "Notebook Hard drive.." for Ubuntu to boot. If you do a restart in Ubuntu it will boot up in win10. If you find how to fix this let me know. Hope this helps.

Comment: You're describing a process on how to erase Windows 10 and install Ubuntu. This is not what the OP wants. Legacy Support is not necessary, and would most likely break Windows 10, as it's probably a UEFI installation.

Comment: No I'm not. Read more carefully. First enable Legacy support then erase and reinstall ubuntu. I have actually done this so I know what I'm talking about. Enabling legacy support does not effect win10.

Comment: But they don't have Ubuntu installed.

Comment: It's probably ther but you have to follow my directions to get it to boot. To boot to Ubuntu U must press ESC after the power button, then press F9 and select "Notebook Hard drive.."  It should boot to Ubuntu. Assuming a LT.